# Why can't access my new state value from another function in react.js hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state-management

I set my marinaList new value. I can access marinaList state in GetMarinaList function. But when I try access marinaList state in GetCounterConnectionDevices function I get inital value of marinaList. Why I can't access my current value of my state in another function ?

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";

function CounterConnectionDeviceDefinition(props) {
    const [marinaList, setMarinaList] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        GetMarinaList();
    }, [])
    const GetMarinaList = () => {
        const RETRIEVED_MARINAS = [
            {
                "Oid": 3348000013080006,
                "Status": 1,
                "LastUpdated": 1615185446387,
                "OperationRefNo": 1459738,
                "MarinaCode": 1,
                "MarinaName": "MERSİN MARİNA",
                "MarinaLocation": "MERSİN",
                "IsActive": true
            },
        ]
        setMarinaList(RETRIEVED_MARINAS)
        console.log(" RETRIEVED_MARINAS", RETRIEVED_MARINAS); //I get retrieved marina data
        GetCounterConnectionDevices(-1);
    }
    const GetCounterConnectionDevices = () => {
        const RETRIEVED_COUNTER_CONNECTION_DEVICES = [
            {
                "Oid": 3348000013898110,
                "Status": 1,
                "LastUpdated": 1618484345355,
                "OperationRefNo": 1498555,
                "PedestalControlCenterOid": 3348000013898011,
                "CounterParameterType": {
                    "Oid": 0,
                    "Status": 0,
                    "LastUpdated": 0,
                    "OperationRefNo": 0,
                    "ParameterTypeOid": 0,
                    "ParameterName": null,
                    "ParameterCode": "001",
                    "ParameterExplanation": null
                },
                "CounterConnectionDeviceModelName": "LUNA_BC62_ANTALYA",
                "CounterConnectionDeviceId": "6-0-64-228-24-0-0-0",
                "CounterConnectionDevicePassword": null,
                "CounterConnectionDeviceIpAddress": null,
                "CounterConnectionDevicePortNumber": null,
                "IsActive": true
            },
        ]
       console.log(" => status.then => RETRIEVED_COUNTER_CONNECTION_DEVICES", RETRIEVED_COUNTER_CONNECTION_DEVICES, marinaList); // I get Retrieved Counter Array and [].  
    }
    return (
        <div>
           
        </div>
    )
}
export default CounterConnectionDeviceDefinition
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `react` updates states async.

This means that `right after` calling `setMarinaList(RETRIEVED_MARINAS)` the state hasn't changed yet. The list is still empty.

That's why you have [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

If you need to run a function when the state changes that's your friend. You can change your code to something like this

```
useEffect(() => {
        const RETRIEVED_COUNTER_CONNECTION_DEVICES = [
            {
                "Oid": 3348000013898110,
                "Status": 1,
                "LastUpdated": 1618484345355,
                "OperationRefNo": 1498555,
                "PedestalControlCenterOid": 3348000013898011,
                "CounterParameterType": {
                    "Oid": 0,
                    "Status": 0,
                    "LastUpdated": 0,
                    "OperationRefNo": 0,
                    "ParameterTypeOid": 0,
                    "ParameterName": null,
                    "ParameterCode": "001",
                    "ParameterExplanation": null
                },
                "CounterConnectionDeviceModelName": "LUNA_BC62_ANTALYA",
                "CounterConnectionDeviceId": "6-0-64-228-24-0-0-0",
                "CounterConnectionDevicePassword": null,
                "CounterConnectionDeviceIpAddress": null,
                "CounterConnectionDevicePortNumber": null,
                "IsActive": true
            },
        ]
       console.log(" => status.then => RETRIEVED_COUNTER_CONNECTION_DEVICES", RETRIEVED_COUNTER_CONNECTION_DEVICES, marinaList); // I get Retrieved Counter Array and [].  
    }, [marinaList])
```

And you can remove `GetCounterConnectionDevices(-1);` call now.

Note: your `useEffect` will also be called once, when the components mounts, so most likely you need to to a check for an empty array.

Comment: that's good answer, thanks. but I have 4 states for GetCounterConnectionDevices(). Do you have another solution for this situation.

Comment: What do you mean that you have 4 states? You need to call the method with different parameters? Then you most likely need another state, that encodes this value and add it as a dependency.

Answer (score -2):

Because everytime you are using your hook in different component youre creating new instance with separated state. If you want to share your state in this hook across multiple components, use [ContextAPI](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) in custom hook